# memory leak in navigation group for Iphone

Tags: iphone, cross-platform, titanium-mobile

I am creating an Iphone App in which i have to open three windows serially again and again using the NavigationGroup. Can any one suggest me how to close a window while using  Navigation. 
          I was trying to make the previous window null after opening the new window . But it is not working. Please help!!!

Thanks in advance

Comment: please post code with question..:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Xcode "Analyze" function to run the static analyzer. It will find most of the basic memory leaks and tell you what to do. In most cases, use `autorelease` on your objects if you want them to be freed when unused.
Setting a "window" to `nil` (null) will not free any memory unless you have declared it as a retaining `@property` and set it to `nil` using `self.property`. Instead, use `autorelease` or `release`.

Answer (score 0):

If you push a view controller and then the user hits the back button the view controller is released by the navigation controller. If it isn't being dealloced then you've got a memory error somewhere in your code.